# Databinding - livedata with custom object not been fired

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I’m facing some issues with databinding and livedata, when I have a custom object.

For example:

I have a `MutableLiveData`
`val user = MutableLiveData<User>()`

and I’m using two way databinding with
`@={viewModel.user.name}`

But my observer its not been fired inside Fragment with
`viewModel.user.observer`.

When I put a breakpoint inside `FragmentBinding` generated class, I can see setValue been called and userLiveData’s user values with data.

The problem is with observer not been fired inside Fragment.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong there?

**EDIT 1**

Below is my fragment code:

```
val infoPessoalViewModel: InfoPessoalViewModel by viewModel()
lateinit var bindingView: FragmentInfoPessoalBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    bindingView = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_info_pessoal, container, false)

    return bindingView.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    bindingView.apply {
        lifecycleOwner = this@InfoPessoalFragment
        viewModel = infoPessoalViewModel
    }

    infoPessoalViewModel.user.observe(this, Observer { user ->
        user.confirmEmail?.let {
            //NOT FIRED HERE
            Log.d("LiveData","Fired!")
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Sorry, I was giving a example variables with diff names.

Comment: Did you call `setLifecycleOwner()` on your `FragmentBinding`?

Comment: Yes mate. I am.

Comment: please post your code, including `onCreateView()` and the observer implementation

Comment: done, with my fragment code

Comment: Okay. First, you should check your BindingAdapter logic. There is a chance that you are updating `User.name`, but not the `User` itself. If you update just a field of the same object `LiveData` will probably not notify observers. Second, use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this` for `LiveData` and data bindings.

Comment: Any idea how to update `User.name` and `User` itself at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Your BindingAdapter logic should be able to convert `EditText` input into a `User` instance and vice versa. Let's say `User` instance looks like this:

**User.kt**

```
class User(val username: String)
```

Then an example adapter should be:

**MyBindingAdapters.kt**

```
/**
 *  Convert EditText input into a User instance.
 */
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
fun getUser(view: EditText): User {
    return User(view.text.toString())
}

/**
 *  Convert a User instance into EditText text
 */
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setUser(view: EditText, newUser: User?) {
    if (newUser?.username != view.text.toString()) {
        view.setText(newUser?.username)
    }
}
```

In your layout file, bind to `userLiveData`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.userLiveData}"/>
```

Notice how the adapters are bijective, meaning one `User` is paired with exactly one `String` and vice versa. If `User` class is more complex, then two-way binding to `MutableLiveData<User>` doesn't really make sense. In such case, you should bind it to `MutableLiveData<String>` instead and manually update `User` instance in the view model.